# adding a table view to a alert view in ios 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uialertview

i want to do something like this..

[image]

i have googled about this but didn't found a good solution or a tutorial.here what i need to do.i want to show a table view inside a alert view.i am not sure how can i do this. some blogs says using delegates we can do this. but i cant understand what are those.can some one clearly tell me step by step what should i do..i am glad if you guide me with code examples or links with great guidance.

thank you

EDIT

can anyone guide me to do this in ios 7... at least the steps i have to follow...

Comment: check this one :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791525/how-to-add-a-uitableview-inside-the-uialertview-in-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You following link download sample code and implement into your project may be solve your problem

[Source Code Link Here.](https://github.com/blommegard/SBTableAlert/)

Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

I used a library for adding a custom view to the alert view. In my case was an `UIPickerView`. Maybe it works with your `Table View`

Can download on that github link: https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Just use this code, after import the custom `Alert View`:

```
UIView *customView ..;

[alertView setContainerView:customView];
```

Answer (score 0):

View this example

https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView

it will help you