# How to create a tableView into AlertView?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a problem, I don't know how to create a tableview into a AlertView like this image:

[image]

Comment: You mean *create instead of "greate"? And I downvoted - please attempt a solution first and provide more information.

Comment: I think you should better create a ViewController for it and present it as popover.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to use a `popover View Controller` instead, but if you MUST do it you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6791659/6772720)

hope this was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIView instead of UIAlertView. It is easy to use.